# Use Eclipse to Programmatically Track Execution Path

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I know that Eclipse has powerful debugging capabilities. Are there any hooks that allow plug-ins to keep track of the code path followed when an open project is run?

For example, suppose I had the following program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = 0;
    if(in.nextInt() == 1) {
      num += 2;
    } else {
      num += 3;
    }

    System.out.println(num);
  }
}
```

Is there some API that Eclipse exposes that would let me make a plug-in that determines which branch of the if statement this program took after it's executed once?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in looking into code coverage. It's a metric used to determine what parts of your code have been run after execution. Typically, it's used for testing purposes, to see what parts of your code aren't run.

That said, you could use it to determine what branch was chosen by only running the program once. [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/), an eclipse plugin, will show you what branches were used by coloring the lines on the editor itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I'm not looking for a plug-in. I want to make a plug-in and am wondering if Eclipse exposes any functionality for me to work with execution path data programatically.